# Do outputs (shp, dwg) inherit vertical datum from input (las) files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, dem, lidar

I'm working in ArcMap. I pulled LiDAR data off earth explorer and created a DEM with the LiDAR data. I then created contours as a SHP file and exported to DWG (CAD). I was asked if the CAD file's vertical datum was NAVD88. I assume it is because I didn't change anything. If the LiDAR data was originally NAVD88, will the CAD file be in NAVD88?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will, I see nothing in this process that would result in a vertical datum change.